# Match a substring between two index in a string

Tags: regex, vba

Hi guys I need a regex that doesn't match if in the first four chars there are the letters `[aue]`
I' ve tried to use this regex `[^aue]{4}`. What am I doing wrong? I'm using vba
Example:
Match the String: xyzoa but not match axyzo because in the first four there is the letter a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not anchoring your regexp.  So it can match anywhere in the string.

This means that it doesn't match either xyzoa or azyxo.  But it matches xyzo from xyzoa and zyxo from azyxo.

To get around this you need to use ^ to indicate start of string;

```
^[^aue]{4}
```

Or if you the match to be the whole string;

```
^[^aue]{4}.*$
```